# Is it possible to 'fork" a repo upto a specific commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is it possible to create a fork in butbucket from a specific commit in a repo? 
I don't want to clone the repo to my machine and then push back. Is there a way to do it from the web interface?

Answer (score 10):

Fork and clone the repo, then use the git command line to reset the branch:

```
git reset --hard <old-commit>
git push -f
```

Comment: Ok, But I was looking for a shortcut specific to bitbucket where I don't have to clone to my machine

Comment: @user2454305, in that case, no, that's not possible. Forking will always create a remote clone of the selected repo; in the true sense: it will exactly copy the whole state of the repo.

Comment: The fork will give a repo with all commit history, then I can roll back to a specific commit '#', right?